# Applying a mask to an multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list, mask, np

I want to do this in a proper way:

```
data = np.array(data)
data =[
[1, 1, 2, 1],
[0, 1, 3, 2],
[0, 2, 3, 2],
[2, 4, 3, 1],
[0, 2, 1, 4],
[3, 1, 4, 1]]
```

this should become (delete the lines that start with 0):

```
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 4, 1]
```

So far I did it like this:

```
lines = []
for i in range(0, len(data[0])):
    if data[0,i] != 0:
        lines.append(data[:,i])
lines = np.array(lines)
```

Then I found this fine method:

```
mask = 1 <= data[0,:]
```

and now I want to apply that mask to that array. This Mask reads: `[True, False, False, True, False, True]`. How do I do that?

Comment: you should specify that you have a numpy array

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
[ar for ar in data if ar[0] != 0]
```

This assumes that arrays are not empty.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have a numpy array based on the  `data[0,:]` and `data[0,i]` you have in your question and you mean `data[:, 0]` :

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [1, 1, 2, 1],
    [0, 1, 3, 2],
    [0, 2, 3, 2],
    [2, 4, 3, 1],
    [0, 2, 1, 4],
    [3, 1, 4, 1]])

data = data[data[:,0] != 0]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 2 1]
 [2 4 3 1]
 [3 1 4 1]]
```

`data[0,:]` is the first row `[1 1 2 1]` not the first column

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I was trying something like `data[data[:,0].all(1)]` but that didn't work :(

Comment: @xtlc, you were not too far off ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using List comprehension

```
In [56]: [elem for elem in data if elem[0] !=0]
Out[56]: [[1, 1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1], [3, 1, 4, 1]]
```